# Formatting an input value as currency in an Angular reactive form

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to format a value as a currency in a nested reactive angular form.

I have an order that has multiple oder items, and I'm creating the form like this:

```
  this.orderForm = this.fb.group({
    id: new FormControl({ value: order.id, disabled: true }),
    orderItems: this.fb.array([])
  });


  get orderItems() {
    return this.orderForm.get('orderItems') as FormArray;
  }
```

And my html:

```
<form [formGroup]="orderForm">
  <div formArrayName="orderItems">
    <div *ngFor="let controls of orderItems.controls;let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Description</mat-label>
        <input matInput formControlName="description">
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Total</mat-label>
        <input type="text" matInput formControlName="total">
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

How do I format the Total as a currency?  I can't do

```
[value]="total | currency"
```

As total isn't a variable, I've also tried

```
[value]="orderItems[i].get('total').value | currency"
```

but that just gives me:

> cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: Why are you attempting to set the value of a `FormControl` to a string? I suggest that you should instead maybe place a dollar sign next to the relevant form field.

Comment: It's not just the dollar sign, it's formatting the 2 decimal places as well, eg 12 = $12.00

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should fix your code:

```
[value]="orderItems.value[i].total | currency"
```

The `value` of the the `orderItems` is the array in this scenario.

Comment: @RobbieMills weird 'cause I just test it and it works for me.

Comment: Yep this did it, I had formatted the field as number, so was showing blank